# Shopware 6.5.0 / removed jquery - how can i add jquery library (jquery-3.6.4.min.js) to my plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins, integration, shopware6, shopware6-app

with come of **Shopware 6.5.0**  - Jquery was **removed** from **CORE**.
My plugin are using Jquery commands, so my question is:

**How can i add Jquery library to my plugin?**  (jquery-3.6.4.min.js)

I did not find nothing about this topic, yet.

Thank you very much for your answer.

Best Regards Petr.

I tried to add this library to my plugin, but somewhere...maybe in layout/**meta.html.twig** it is needed to add. But i did not find correct solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I collected some information for you:

Please read this:

- https://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery/why-not/
- https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/
- and the changelog of shopware: https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/UPGRADE-6.5.md#javascriptjquery